# Apache JCR with failover - Hadoop?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, jcr, failover

We're looking how to implement a failover with JCR. Aka, a secondary server can take the 'master' position in case of trouble. I'm unable to find something on the subject, so some help would be welcomed.

It's possible to combine JCR and Hadoop ? JCR and MongoDB ?

Answer (score 1):

The JCR 2.0 RI Jackrabitt "Oak" provide a MongoDB integration (MongoDB Storage) that supports all the features of MongoDB (Replication & Sharding)

You cand find information here:
- http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/dev_getting_started.html

Answer (score 1):

I have just recently Open Sourced a JCR Browser that is built on Apache Oak JCR + MongoDB + SpringBoot and has a front end on JQueryMobile. It is on GitHub (including all source), and here is the site too: 
http://meta64.com